# String concatenation without a delimiter

Tags: java, string

I'm having a string. This String is built by concatenating a username(can be any random name) and a phone number(phone number consist with 11 or 15 number of digits).
for an example if we take the username as "john1243" and if we take a 11 digit phone number as "27456985321" and then the final String would be "john124327456985321". in here i get only the final String(no delimiters either). Is there a way I could split that in to the exact username and the phone number?

only thing that I know is the phone number can be either a 11 digit or a 15 digit number.

Can anybody give me a clue how to start solving this problem and any help would be really appreciated in advance.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a delimiter? Or is that actually the problem?

Comment: You would get two strings one with last 11 digit and other with last 15 digit, there is no escape from that. One way to avoid 15 is if by any chance you see overlap with characters. You could then check whether after removing last 11 characters that user exist or after removing 15 digit does that user exist?

Comment: If I give you the string `Thomas12345678901234567` could _you_ tell me whether my phone number was `345678901234567` or `78901234567`?

Comment: @qvotaxon Nope, there isn't any chance of adding a delimiter. That's the problem.

Comment: @SMA We cannot check whether user exist or not.

Comment: You could ring them up, and ask what their username is. If not, you go on dialling the next person. Of course I'm kidding. But if you don't add a delimiter, it will be (nearly) impossible to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Thomas I know what you are trying to say. I also feel like the same way. But the problem is what I'm only getting is "Thomas12345678901234567" and i need to find your phone number and the username SOMEHOW and I only knows that the number of digits for the phone number can be either 11 or 15.

Comment: Better ask the one who is sending you the data to use delimiters..;)

Comment: If you really can't get the provider of the data to add delimiters (and that should be your top priority) then the only thing could be to guess: take the number (either 11 or 15-digit) that _more_ looks like a phone number (depends on how much you need on what's possible/allowed in a phone number). It's still a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem with using max (15) digits of phone number?

Example1: name Jhon12345 phone 12345678901 -> phone=000012345678901

---> Str Jhon12345000012345678901.

---> Name = Str.substring(0, Str.lengh()-15) = Jhon12345

---> Phone = Str.substring(Str.lengh()-15) = 000012345678901. Just remove first 0s...

Example2: name Guedes0000 ponhe 12345678901234
---> Str Guedes000012345678901234.

---> Name = Str.substring(0, Str.lengh()-15) = Guedes0000

---> Phone = Str.substring(Str.lengh()-15) = 12345678901234. No zeros to remove...

Comment: I think the OP isn't creating the concatenated string, he's just getting them like that.

Comment: ok, i this case, like said SMA in an comment, the olny option is to remove fist 11, and check if username exists... If not, remove 15 digits and check again. But in this case, theres an problem if both users exists... GUEDES1234 tel 12345678901 and GUEDES tel 123412345678901